# sudoers Entry Won't Take

Tags: big-sur

`Big Sur` won't take my user entry into `sudoers` for some reason.  I've used both `sudo visudo` and `nano` and the entry remains.  Here's the entry:

```
phil            ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

I test it with `sudo echo alpha` and it asks me for my password.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I can't live this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should get asked for your password when you use sudo, based on the entry in `sudoers` you've posted - it's asking for your password to raise privilege to make sure it is really you. This is expected behaviour.

If you enter your password, and it then works, your `sudoers` entries are valid.

Comment: Ah I see the reference I used was wrong then.  I entered `NOPASSWD`, works.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Hey glad to be sorted.  Having to enter passwords at every breath is intimidating.  Much like being married.  Heh.